# Does Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty PS command excist in W7?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

i'm trying to find the equivalent of the W2K8R2 server powershell command for "Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty", does it excist in W7?

Comment: is that ps command native to w2k8r2?

Comment: it says so : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130901.aspx

Comment: unfortuantely that link is probably for 2012 its kinda not specific as far as I can tell but I'm sure its talking about 2012.

Comment: so there's no alternative for W7....snif...